# Gave someone piano lessons (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Let's say you are telling someone your childhood life as for you playing a musical instrument, the piano.

> Someone: Do you play the piano?
>
> You: Not anymore. My mom **gave me piano lessons** when I was a kid, but I hated it.

What is the meaning of that? Does it mean that your mom "used to" teach you piano lessons herself or she had you enrolled in a piano school?

Comment: The mom taught the child. It's her who gave the lessons/instructions.

Comment: I see, but I think there's something else behind the word "gave" because the speaker should have just said "teach" instead of changing it into "gave" right?

Comment: You can't say 'they _should_ have said 'teach'. _My mom taught me to play the piano_ could be understood to mean that the speaker can play now, but in fact they had some lessons and hated it, so they have probably forgotten what they  learned.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that if *A gives something to B,* it means that *B* received it from *A.* That said, it's the mom who taught or gave lessons of the piano to the kid.

The speaker used *gave* because it was the mom who was child's *guru.* Had she enrolled the kid, it'd have been like -

> ..... my mom *got me enrolled* in some piano school.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a piano teacher, so I can tell you from a wealth of experience that in common usage, anyone who "gives lessons" is a piano teacher.

That said, I can understand why someone would want to use the word "give" to say that their parents arranged for them to take lessons. There's nothing wrong with using "give" in this context from a grammar standpoint. This is a correct useage of the word "give." The only problem is in common usage: "give" in this context is reserved to describe the piano teacher.